# How to create a 2d geometric transformation matrix to stretch an image along a given direction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to define a matrix to stretch an image along a given direction.

For exemple, I have an angle alpha and a scaling ratio r. How can I construct the transformation matrix in order to apply the scaling along the axis that makes an angle alpha with the horizontal?

My attempt so far was:

```
 [r*cos(alpha) 0             0
  0            r*sin(alpha)  0
  0            0             1]
```

But it does not give me what I want. If r<1, I expect my first element to be bigger than r, but it is obviously not the case as cos(alpha)<=1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should revise your expectations :) Scaling with a factor of $<1$ will make the image smaller, thus all diagonal entries will be $<1$ as well. In fact, $a_{ii} \leq r$ with $= r$ exactly when $\alpha$ is aligned with the respective axis.

Comment: Yeah, now that you say it... So, is my matrix correct?

Comment: Whatever your third component is to be, but the first two are, provided they are corresponding to x/y coordinates, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the transformation is in 2d, the matrices ought to be $2\times 2$. I would build the matrix in three steps:

1. Rotate the plane so that the axis of  stretching becomes the $x$-axis:
   $$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{pmatrix}$$
2. Stretch by factor $r$ along the $x$ axis: 
   $$A_2=\begin{pmatrix} r & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
3. Rotate the plane back:
   $$A_3=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\  \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix that you want is the product  of the above: 
$$A_3A_2A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1+(r-1)\cos^2 \alpha & (r-1) \sin \alpha\cos\alpha \\ (r-1) \sin \alpha\cos\alpha & 1+(r-1)\sin^2 \alpha \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for digging up this old post, I did exactly that. My matrix is in 3d because it represents an image and the 3rd dimension is the pixel intensity.